# How would I make inset grouped UITavleView appear as such?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, appearance

How would I make inset grouped table appear as such?
I have cells stretch edge to edge.
After switching to inset grouped I expected padding on the left and right of the cells.

Forcing the offsets like this

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: .horizontalMargin, bottom: 0, right: .horizontalMargin)
```

or

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: .horizontalMargin, bottom: 0, right: -.horizontalMargin)
```

causes the cell to be offset on the left but clipped on the right?!???

Enlighten me please. This must be trivial but somehow is not :-[
The VC is derived from UITableViewController

the layout is in xib

Answer (score 0):

Apparently inset grouped appearance was added only in ios13 and
that style is ignored on ios12 i was testing on :-O